# Best choice for hosting Maven repository and continuous integration?

Tags: maven-2, continuous-integration, repository

Can anyone recommend a good hosting provider where we can host our Maven 2 repository and continuous integration process?

We're very open minded about the implementation and are willing to use any OS, CI software and repository software so long as it gets the job done well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Update: I'm interested in finding a hosting solutions where I basically click a button and everything is setup and hosted for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

we are using nexus community edition (@see http://www.sonatype.com/products/nexus) for caching external artifacts and publishing internal releases and snapshots.

we evaluated some tools for continuous integration (@see http://continuum.apache.org , @see https://hudson.dev.java.net) and decided to use hudson because of its simplicity.

Comment: But are you hosing this yourself or are you paying someone to host it?  I'm interested in finding a hosting solutions where I basically click a button and everything is setup and hosted for me.

Comment: we are hosting it on our own, but have good experience with http://www.assembla.com/

Comment: +1 for Hudson. We are using Artifactory for repository, very simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

Sonatype will host your project artifacts if it is open source. See [here](https://docs.sonatype.com/display/NX/OSS+Repository+Hosting) for details.

You can get Bamboo hosting from [one of their partners](http://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=162718)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any SaaS provider who hosts maven/nexus/sonar. I know of beanstalk and springloops. Both are SaaS provider but don't target your requirements. Maybe, you could use amazon ec2 and deploy you own virtual machine with nexus.  [Nexus Open Source and Hudson on EC2](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/06/nexus-open-source-and-hudson-on-ec2/)